# Random Stock Stop-Loss/Stop

Tags: probability, random, finance

Assuming a Stock's price changes in a random manner.  If you buy this Stock, you are required to set a stop-return and stop-loss price. I am looking for the equation that shows the probability for each day since you buy the Stock (Buy Date), of crossing the stop-return and stop-loss price.  In other words; I want the formula that allows me to chart a line showing the probability the Stock price crossing any stop-loss (on way down) or stop-return on way up.

The stop-loss price can be any price below the Buy price.
The stop-return price can be any price higher than the Buy price.
Known Information:  1. The Buy Price.  2. The Standard Deviation (or Historical Volatility) of the Price on the date you bought the Stock.

For example, on the x-axis of  the chart it displays each day starting with the Buy Date.  There are 2 lines.  One line shows the probability of the random price crosses the stop-loss price going down for each day.  The other line shows the probability the random price crosses the stop-return price going up on the same day.

My suspicion is that the solution is some log-normal density function.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: How about considering a 1D random walk with equal probabilities of increasing or decreasing and equal step? (By the way, is this a homework problem?)

Comment: "Price changes in a random manner": The answer will depend on the stochastic model you choose for your stock.  Given your mention of standard deviation, are you thinking of using something like a geometric Brownian motion (Black-Scholes model)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You are probably expected to assume an independent daily normal distribution of price changes (in percent or in absolute dollars?).  The variance on one day is the square of the standard deviation and variances add.  As a function of the day number $n$, the number of standard deviations of movement decreases as $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$.  For each span of days, figure out how many s.d. you have to move and look it up in your normal probability table.

Comment: You are correct, if there are no stop-loss or stop-returns.  My question has to do with how different stop-loss levels effect the stop-return probability.  Ross, I am not clear how the stop-loss/return is included in your answer.  Like George Williams suggested, I did explore 1-Dimensional random walk, but I got stuck.  Any help if appreciated.

Comment: @taun:  Say a stock price variation has a daily standard deviation of $ \$1$ per day.  If your stop loss if $\$5$ from where you bought, it is very unlikely to trigger the next day.  It has a fair chance of triggering within $25$ days.  This is the random walk, which has the expected distance from the origin grow with the square root of the number of steps.